# Convert CSV file into array of hashes

Tags: ruby, csv, multidimensional-array

I have a csv file, some hockey stats, for example:

```
09.09.2008,1,HC Vitkovice Steel,BK Mlada Boleslav,1:0 (PP)
09.09.2008,1,HC Lasselsberger Plzen,RI OKNA ZLIN,6:2
09.09.2008,1,HC Litvinov,HC Sparta Praha,3:5
```

I want to save them in an array of hashes. I don't have any headers and I would like to add keys to each value like `"time" => "09.09.2008"` and so on. Each line should by accessible like `arr[i]`, each value by for example `arr[i]["time"]`. I prefer `CSV` class rather than `FasterCSV` or `split`. Can you show the way or redirect to some thread where a similar problem was solved?

Comment: What is `so on`? Other than `"time"`, we have no clue what keys you want. Maybe you should show the expected output.

Comment: so on.. I meant etc. , my english isn't probably so good. Other key could be round, home and visiting team and score. Expected Output is {["time" => "09.09.2008", "round" => "1", "home" => "Vitkovice Steel", "visiting" => "BK Mlada Boleslav", "score" => "1:0 (PP)"],[next lines...]}

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use the [Ruby CSV parser](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) to parse it, and then use `Hash[ keys.zip(values) ]` to make it a hash.

Example:

```
test = '''
09.09.2008,1,HC Vitkovice Steel,BK Mlada Boleslav,1:0 (PP)
09.09.2008,1,HC Lasselsberger Plzen,RI OKNA ZLIN,6:2
09.09.2008,1,HC Litvinov,HC Sparta Praha,3:5
'''.strip

keys = ['time', etc... ]
CSV.parse(test).map {|a| Hash[ keys.zip(a) ] }
```

Comment: I tried that 'require 'csv'

csv_data = CSV.read 'data.txt'
keys = ['time',"round","home","visiting","score"]
CSV.parse(csv_data).map {|a| Hash[ keys.zip(a) ] }' but i probably didn catch the idea because it returned some errors

Comment: c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1381:in `ensure in parse': undefined method `close' for #<Array:0x8f2050> (NoMethodError)
 from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1381:in `parse'
 from C:/Users/Mythago/My Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/elh stats/main.rb:5:in `<main>'

Comment: looks like you're calling close on the array. Dont do that

Comment: @user1955522 CSV.parse method accepts string as its argument, not an array. Try `CSV.read('data.txt').map {|a| Hash[ keys.zip(a) ]}` .

Comment: Beautiful code. This is a great example of Ruby's strengths!

Answer (score 94):

## Just pass `headers: true`

```
CSV.foreach(data_file, headers: true) do |row|
  puts row.inspect # hash
end
```

From there, you can manipulate the hash however you like.

(Tested with Ruby 2.0, but I think this has worked for quite a while.)

### Edit

You say you don't have any headers - could you add a header line to the beginning of the file contents after reading them?

Comment: Technically, I think each row is an instance of `CSV::Row`, which acts like a `Hash` but doesn't actually inherit `Hash`.

Comment: You can also use `CSV.parse(data, headers: true).map(&:to_h)` to similar effect, taking into account Jared's note above. This turns your CSV into an array of hashes with headers as keys. You can also want to toss in the option `header_converters: :symbol` to use symbols as keys instead of the column name as strings.

Answer (score 43):

This is a [fantastic post](http://technicalpickles.com/posts/parsing-csv-with-ruby) by Josh Nichols which explains how to do what you're asking.

To summarize, here his code:

```
csv = CSV.new(body, :headers => true, :header_converters => :symbol, :converters => [:all, :blank_to_nil])
csv.to_a.map {|row| row.to_hash }
=> [{:year=>1997, :make=>"Ford", :model=>"E350", :description=>"ac, abs, moon", :price=>3000.0}, {:year=>1999, :make=>"Chevy", :model=>"Venture \"Extended Edition\"", :description=>nil, :price=>4900.0}, {:year=>1999, :make=>"Chevy", :model=>"Venture \"Extended Edition, Very Large\"", :description=>nil, :price=>5000.0}, {:year=>1996, :make=>"Jeep", :model=>"Grand Cherokee", :description=>"MUST SELL!\nair, moon roof, loaded", :price=>4799.0}]
```

So, you could save the body of your CSV file into a string called `body`.

```
body = "09.09.2008,1,HC Vitkovice Steel,BK Mlada Boleslav,1:0 (PP)
09.09.2008,1,HC Lasselsberger Plzen,RI OKNA ZLIN,6:2
09.09.2008,1,HC Litvinov,HC Sparta Praha,3:5"
```

And then run his code as listed above on it.

Comment: Thanks for the post reference, very useful. I'm not sure if it was my data specifically; however, I needed to ommit the `:blank_to_nil` otherwise I was getting an error `*** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `arity' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: @CodeBiker @shakerlxxv   I have the same error message, NoMethodError: undefined method `encode` for nil:Nilclass.  What is the solution to get it working?

Comment: @user2012677, I omitted the `:blank_to_nil` converter, so my final expression looks like `CSV.new(File.new(file), :headers => true, :header_converters => :symbol, :converters => [:all]).to_a.map {|row| row.to_hash }`

Comment: You can also reduce it to this: `CSV.new(body, headers: true).map(&:to_hash)` (in Ruby 2.1.5, at least)

Comment: I like Pavel's solution above better

Answer (score 39):

A little shorter solution

Parse string:

```
CSV.parse(content, headers: :first_row).map(&:to_h)
```

Parse file:

```
CSV.open(filename, headers: :first_row).map(&:to_h)
```

Comment: Parse file code lead to:
`/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/csv.rb:1764:in `to_h': wrong element type String at 0 (expected array) (TypeError)`

Answer (score 8):

Slight variation on [Nathan Long](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4376/nathan-long%20%22Nathan%20Long%22%20%27s%20answer)'s answer

```
data_file = './sheet.csv'
data = CSV.foreach(data_file, headers: true).map(&:to_h)
```

Now `data` is an array of hashes to do your bidding with!

Comment: Even leaner: `data = CSV.foreach(data_file, headers: true).map{ |row| row.to_h }`

Comment: Even leaner than that: `data = CSV.foreach(data_file, headers: true).map(&:to_h)` :D

Answer (score 2):

The `headers` option to the CSV module accepts an array of strings to be used as the headers, when they're not present as the first row in the CSV content.

```
CSV.parse(content, headers: %w(time number team_1 team_2 score))
```

This will generate an enumerable of hashes using the given headers as keys.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following gem also

```
require 'csv_hasher'
arr_of_hashes = CSVHasher.hashify('/path/to/csv/file')
```

The keys of the returned hashes will be the header values of the csv file.

If you want to pass your own keys then

```
keys = [:key1, :key2, ... ]
arr_of_hashers = CSVHasher.hashify('/path/to/csv/file', { keys: keys })
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is the shortest version:

```
keys = ["time", ...]
CSV.parse(content, headers: keys).map(&:to_h)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also use the [SmarterCSV](https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv) gem,
which returns data from CSV files as Ruby hashes by default.

It has a lot of features, including processing the data in chunks, which is very benefitial for huge data files.

```
  require 'smarter_csv'

  options = {} # see GitHub README
  data = SmarterCSV.process(your_file_name, options)
```

Answer (score 0):

For me

```
data_file = 'file.csv'
data = CSV.foreach(data_file, headers: true).map(&:to_h)
```

works as mentioned by `lacostenycoder` with that your csv file with the content let's say

```
id,amount
1,10.10
2,20.20
```

will be converted to

```
[{"id"=>"1", "amount"=>"10.10"},
 {"id"=>"2", "amount"=>"20.20"}]
```