# How to make a CSV file into a hash

Tags: ruby, csv, hash

In ruby, if I have a CSV file that looks like this:

make,model,color,doors
dodge,charger,black,4
ford,focus,blue,5
nissan,350z,black,2
mazda,miata,white,2
honda,civid,brown,4
corvette,stingray,red,2
ford,fiesta,blue,5

How would I be able to turn this CSV data into a hash and be able to manipulate it as a regular hash. I tried looking for an answer in StackOverflow but could not seem to find one. I tried to find other example online as well but they did not exactly work.

Comment: You have a two-dimensional data structure there. Parsing  it into just a hash doesn't make much sense here. You can however [easily parse it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20846047/421705) into an array of hashes (one hash per line). If this does not meet your requirement, please edit your question and show an example of the data structure you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to just try

```
require 'csv'

CSV.open(filename, headers: :first_row).map(&:to_h)
```

Also you can get reference form below link

[Convert CSV file into array of hashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14199784/convert-csv-file-into-array-of-hashes)